# Mac OS X Server add server user

Tags: mac-osx, svn, user-management, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

What's the recommended way to add a user to Mac OS X Server that doesn't need all the hoopla associated with `Workgroup Manager`? There are many users pre-configured in Mac OS X Server (`www`, `root`, `ldapadmin`, etc.) that don't have "Full Name" or mail accounts, etc.

I'd like to create a 'svn' user to be the owner of our Subversion Repository as per this tutorial:

> If you've decided to use either Apache
>   or stock **svnserve**, create a single **svn**
>   user on your system and run the server
>   process as that user. Be sure to make
>   the repository directory wholly owned
>   by the **svn** user as well. From a
>   security point of view, this keeps the
>   repository data nicely siloed and
>   protected by operating system
>   filesystem permissions, changeable by
>   only the Sub- version server process
>   itself.

Wondering if there's a way outside of WorkgroupManager and OpenDirectory as this account will be entirely server based. Is this still sound advice under OS X Server? If so what's the easiest way to create the user (Mac OS X Server doesn't seem to respond to `useradd`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add accounts with the `dscl` command line utility. Depending on where you want to add users (just on that server, or on all machines via OpenDirectory), you can pass an argument to it.

For a standard OD, adding a user looks like:
`dscl -u USERNAME -P Password /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 -create /Users/USERNAME UniqueID <put unique ID here>`

For a local user, like this:
`dscl -u USERNAME -P Password / -create /Users/USERNAME UniqueID <put unique ID here>`

You'll need a different dscl command for various user attributes. There is a guide for a standard-type user account here: http://osxdaily.com/2007/10/29/how-to-add-a-user-from-the-os-x-command-line-works-with-leopard/

And as always, `man dscl`!

Answer (score 0):

Create the use from the System Preferences, Accounts and make it a Standard user. And after you create the account, if you Control + click on the user you can choose the shell, shortname, home folder, etc. for that user.

This user will be a local user only (ie: not part of the OpenDirectory users)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this from within Workgroup Manager.  There's a hidden pop-up menu just below the toolbar (where it says something like Authenticated as diradmin to directory: /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1); select Local from that pop-up, authenticate if necessary (there's a padlock at the right just under the toolbar), and you'll be editing the purely local accounts on the server (technically, the /Local/Default domain).  You can create accounts as you please here, and just leave off irrelevant attributes (except the Full Name; that's required no matter how you create the account).